# Prevent useState / useEffect from changing pre rendered html on initial load

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

My initial page is a pre-rendered html page containing a list of fetched todos.(SSG)

The index.js uses ReactDOM.hydrateRoot instead of render to convert the static html into the react components.

However... because the app uses both useState and useEffect to load the todos, it immediately clears the pre-rendered html todos and makes a new request for the todo's.

I can prevent the useEffect from running on the initial load however for some reason the pre-rendered todo's are still getting cleared, and i'm not sure why.

```
  const [keep_pre_rendered_todos, update_pre_rendered_todos] = useState(true);
  const [todos, setData] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    
    if(keep_pre_rendered_todos) return; // STOPS useEffect RUNNING ON INITIAL LOAD
    
    fetch("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos")
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((todos) => setData(todos))
      .catch((error) => {
        alert(error+"An error occurred!")
      });

  }, true);

  return (
    <div className="todos">
      {
        todos &&
        todos.map((task) =>
          <div className="todo" key={task.id}>
            {task.title}
          </div>
        )
      }
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: How is this page bootstrapped? Are you using any framework for SSG?

Comment: No. I’ve not got that far yet!.. finding a way to dynamically create ssg pages that include fetched data will be my next problem!.. Currently I’m just trying to get my head around how to get the app working when starting with rendered html.  I’ve just mocked up an html page with the html todo content, it seems to work fine, but I can’t stop the app from either re populating the fetched todo data or just removing them if you prevent the useEffect running.

Comment: Ah, I see. It's actually simple: when SSR'd, you make the values come as props, and then you use such props to initialize the state. Makes sense?

Comment: Thanks @acdcjunior - I can initialise the useState with a value, however because I am running the app from static html, i'm not sure how to get that value to initialise it.. I had hoped there'd be an option for useState to not run on first pass... or a way to get the value after hydrateRoot.. (I imagine this is an option, but I'm not sure where to start)... alternatively I guess I could store the data in an object within the static html and then have access to it, however it feels like this would be a bit of a hack.